# How to tidy huge blank spaces in data_frame?

Tags: r, lag, tidyr

I've got some data pulled from the web that has about 15,000 rows. The date column has a date at the beginning of each 'block section' of data. About 25% of which is blank. So it's a column that will have one cell of 2010, then NA's for a while, then 2010 again. Basically, the date is the same . . . until it changes. I've pulled a date variable out and it looks like the Date_from source column in the following code:

```
data_frame(
  Date_from_source = 
    c(2010,rep(NA,2),2010,rep(NA,2),2011,rep(NA,3),2011,rep(NA,2),2012), 
  Date_tidy = c(rep(2010,6),rep(2011,7),2012))
```

I'm stuck on how to code the Data_from_source column into a Date_tidy column. I've tried using a group_by and lag approach, but I'm spinning my wheels.  Thanks.

Comment: Not entirely sure what you're trying to see as a result, can you give an example of what output you expect

Comment: You might be looking for `tidyr::fill`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for `tidyr::fill`

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
df1 <- data_frame(
  Gender = sample(c('male','female'),14,T),
  Date_from_source = 
    c(2010,rep(NA,2),2010,rep(NA,2),2011,rep(NA,3),2011,rep(NA,2),2012), 
  Date_tidy = c(rep(2010,6),rep(2011,7),2012))

df1 %>% group_by(Gender) %>% fill(Date_from_source)

    # # A tibble: 14 x 3
    # # Groups:   Gender [2]
    # Gender Date_from_source Date_tidy
    # <chr>            <dbl>     <dbl>
    #  1 female               NA      2010
    #  2 female             2011      2011
    #  3 female             2011      2011
    #  4 female             2011      2011
    #  5 female             2011      2011
    #  6   male             2010      2010
    #  7   male             2010      2010
    #  8   male             2010      2010
    #  9   male             2010      2010
    # 10   male             2010      2010
    # 11   male             2010      2011
    # 12   male             2010      2011
    # 13   male             2010      2011
    # 14   male             2012      2012
```

Comment: I see you changed your sample data in the meantime but it should work the same, the remaining NA remaining is because it can't guess the first one as there's nothing before, use `fill(Date_from_source,.direction="up")` at the end of the chain if you want your NAs to be equal to the min year
`

Comment: thanks for this.  How would this work if the Gender column also had huge gaps or  NA's?  I should have included NA's in the Gender column.  I'm going to do another edit and remove it all together. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: It looks like it works just the same! Thanks for this.